# JQ Grid Date Format

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

Hello guys am using a JQ Grid and the date format am getting is 2012-09-16T00:00:00 like this. I want the date format to be in 2012-09-16 manner. 
I have tried to change it but it's not working. Please have a look at my code and tell me where am going wrong.

formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { 'srcformat' : 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 'newformat' : 'Y-m-d' }

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I can't reproduce your problem. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AshishBatra.htm) for example.

Answer (score 2):

Replace below colModel with your code

```
{name:'createDate',index:'createdDate', width:80, formatter : 'date', formatoptions : {newformat : 'Y-m-d'} },
```

Answer (score 2):

It May Help You!!!

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="___" index="___" title="Date" sortable="true" width="70" align="right" formatter="date" formatoptions= "{srcformat:'y-m-d', newformat: 'Y-m-d' }"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 4.8.  I had the same exact problem, I think I was using 4.5 as well.